# What powerbank can I use on the flight?

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items, power

I'm going on a flight for 5 hours and will be using my iPad Air for watching video.

The battery will be used quickly, so I need a power bank that will be able to charge it on the fly.

Are there any restrictions for using a powerbank on the flight? What kind of powerbank is allowed?

Comment: Note the battery capacity of your iPad and the number of hours it runs off it. Choose a power bank with enough capacity to cover the remaining hours assuming the same discharge rate.

Comment: What airline and which countries are involved? Some of the rules differ.

Comment: Also a lot of modern planes these days offer seat back power outlets.  Some are full voltage AC while others are simple USB.  So what airline and what flight?  You may not even need a power bank.

Answer (score 5):

During extensive travel through Europe, America and Asia I have not seen restrictions that have an issue with power banks below 20000mAh. With this in mind, a ~16000mAh power bank would be a fine option; the ipad air battery capacity is somewhere around 8000mAh so you would have a pack that could effectively triple your devices on-time.

Officially, the [IATA](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Pages/lithium-batteries.aspx) guidelines limit you by Watt Hours, which is *Amp Hour x Voltage*. Their [passenger guide](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf) shows what these limits are, but you will find that precise limits vary between airlines, such as BA only allowing up to 4 spare batteries per passenger.

Answer (score 5):

It will depend on the capacity in Wh (watt hours) but most commercially available ones should be OK. The IATA guidelines say that under 100Wh (multiply Ah x V to get Wh) is OK to bring on board and in cargo if installed in equipment. If they are loose spare batteries you can bring as many in carry on but not in the hold. Between 100-160Wh same applies but you are restricted to 2 spare loose batteries and again not allowed to check in. If over 160Wh you have to declare it and it has to be packed in cargo under the Dangerous Goods guidelines.Most airlines follow the IATA guidelines.

[image]